# sound record tickling / ticks / noises / spikes

Tags: android, audio-recording

I successfully record sound on an Android 2.3.4 device (full settings are: `AudioSource.MIC` + `44100Hz` + `AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO` + `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT`).

I also properly write the PCM data to a WAV file.

The problem is that there are those noises which makes the recording terrible.

The **[attached file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/dp4niw) shows exactly what I mean**. Notice the obvious spikes.

**I have tested the same** recording (the music in the attached file) **with some sound recording apps on the market, and they record in a perfect way**, without noises at all - how is it done? Is it a setting I should set (I use `AudioRecord`)? Should I manually filter those noises with some algorithm? What should I be looking for?

If the attached file is not downloading for some reason or link is simply broken just let me know with a comment.

Thanks!

Edit #1:
I'm with Galaxy S2.

Comment: This could be a hardware problem. I've noticed on some phones and small cameras, that the microphone is susceptible to bumps and knocks when he device is manipulated in space. So, moving your S2 around while recording **might** be causing the spikes. Have you been able to rule this out?

Comment: @JamieTaylor Hi, yes - it's definitely not the case as I record sound while the device is on the table - not moving whatsoever.

Comment: And just to emphasize, again - in the exact same conditions I use another recording software and it gives perfect sound. Weird.

Comment: I just thought I'd ask, to make sure. Ya know? :-)

Comment: I'd do the same, that's ok :)

Comment: i have the problem with file size for recording sample rate  with 44100. so that i tried different sample rates such as 8000, 11025, 22050, 32000, 44056 but no use. however some devices accept the audio configuration but audio quality is too worst. some devices shows errors with invalid buffer size or invalid audio configuration. i am totally confused how to record clear audio with low file size. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 44100Hz is too much for your phone capability, and in general, for all phones capabilities: mobile phones are not HI-FI.

Try with 8000Hz.

Then you can change this value until you find an acceptable recording quality.

Comment: Hi rosco, I don't think so. I'm with Galaxy S2 that's one. Second, another recording app, as I've said in the original post, records perfectly the same sound I try to record with my own code.

Comment: ok. but, have you tried? or you are sure that your app uses the same algorithm of the other recording app? 44100Hz is the number of samples per seconds (CD quality), you need a very good HW and SW to encode and decode it. just try and verify if it is better/equal/worst and then decide your next steps :)

Comment: I've tried and you're correct. More than that, I've also found out that providing AudioRecord a bigger buffer than `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()` suggests does clear the sound even in 44100Hz. Thanks :)

Comment: i have the problem with file size for recording sample rate  with 44100. so that i tried different sample rates such as 8000, 11025, 22050, 32000, 44056 but no use. however some devices accept the audio configuration but audio quality is too worst. some devices shows errors with invalid buffer size or invalid audio configuration. i am totally confused how to record clear audio with low file size. please help me.