# How to compress WAV file on android

Tags: android, audio, compression, audio-recording

in my app i am recording voice using AudioRecorder as given in the following site [Audio Recorder](http://matrix-examplecode.blogspot.in/2011/12/audio-recording-part-2.html)
it is working but it produce large size WAV file. for example if i record audio for **1 minute it takes 2MB to 3MB.** So that i must compress the WAV file to small size file. i have tried long time to get but i could not get any ideas. i have tried different **SAMPLERATE such as 8000, 11025, 22050, 32000, 44056** but i get app crashes with invalid buffer size,invalid audio configuration and some time working but voice quality is too bad.**the SAMPLE_RATE = 44100 only working perfect but result file size is too large.** please help me to compress the wav file ,give some example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Q: Are you able to use an alread-compressed format, like .mp3 or .ogg/Vorbis?  Ideally, you can just read and write .ogg files - that would give you the best of all worlds.

Comment: How to convert raw stream to mp3 or ogg? i do not know much about audio format converting. please give examples or ideas. thanks for valuable comment.

Comment: You could use libsndfile to convert to various formats, or libsox.

Comment: try reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495779/sound-record-tickling-ticks-noises-spikes : changing sample_rate needs other changes in input parameters.